# cloudformation delay resource creation within the same stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

is it possible to delay resource creation within the same stack? I have a DC and another server that needs to join to the domain once the DC is all set up. Both servers are created within the same stack. I tried using the waithandle however it still creates both resources at the same time and then says creation in progress for the duration of the wait handle.

edit: code as requested:
1. userdata of DC server

```
        # "Fn::Base64":
    #   Fn::Join ["", [
    #   "<script>cfn-init -v --stack ", !Ref "AWS::StackName", " --resource DC --configsets ascending --region", !Ref "AWS::Region", "\n",
    #   "cfn-signal.exe -e 0 ", Fn::Base64 !Ref DCServerWaitHandle, "</script>"]]
```

wait handles

```
DCServerWaitHandle:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
DCServerWaitCondition:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
  DependsOn: DC
  Properties:
    Handle: !Ref DCServerWaitHandle
    Timeout: 600
```

then the other server which should wait for 600 seconds for the DC to build has a dependon: DC property

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use **DependsOn** feature to create resources in order.
For EC2 instances in particular you can use a [CreationPolicy Attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html) to prevent a resource get to complete status.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitconditionhandle.html):

> For Amazon EC2 and Auto Scaling resources, we recommend that you use a CreationPolicy attribute instead of wait conditions. Add a CreationPolicy attribute to those resources, and use the cfn-signal helper script to signal when an instance creation process has completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom resource that can be used as a delay for any arbitrary resource. Can simply add a couple DependsOn and you are in business.

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/589

For Example:

```
   TGWAttachmentPeering:
      Condition: CreateTGWPeering
      Type: AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayPeeringAttachment
      Properties: 
        PeerAccountId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
        PeerRegion: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref AWS::Region, opposite]
        PeerTransitGatewayId: !Ref PeerTransitGatewayId
        TransitGatewayId: !Ref TransitGateway
      CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:    
          Count: Integer
          Timeout: String


    TGWRouteTable:
      Condition: CreateTGWPeering
      Type: AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRouteTable
      Properties:
        Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Sub VPC-${VPCNumber}
        TransitGatewayId: !Ref TransitGateway

    Delay: #https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/589#issuecomment-671111145
      Condition: CreateTGWPeering
      DependsOn: TGWAttachmentPeering
      Type: Community::CloudFormation::Delay
      Properties:
        Duration: PT300S

    TGWPeeringRoute:
      Condition: CreateTGWPeering
      DependsOn: Delay
      Type: AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: 
          !Sub 
            - 1.${cidrRange}.0.0/16
            - cidrRange: !FindInMap [VPCMap, !Ref VPCNumber, opposite]
        TransitGatewayRouteTableId: !Ref TGWRouteTable
        TransitGatewayAttachmentId: !Ref TGWAttachmentPeering
```